# Accessing .html file in my Supporting Files directory on iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager

I was trying to display formatted text and did some research here on SO and ppl said to draw it with CG or use html and throw it in a UIWebView.  As UIWebView being the easier option, I formatted my document in .html and dropped it into my folder like so:

```
Supporting Files/Data/Template.html
```

How do I access this file to show in a UIWebView?

I know I can get my documents by doing:

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

But after that, I'm stuck.  I'm not sure how I would access my Template.html.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you already have the NSURL to the offline template.html file.

```
NSURLRequest * offlineRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:offlineURL];
UIWebView * webview = [[[UIWebView alloc] init] autorelease];
[webview loadRequest:offlineRequest];
```

Comment: No I don't have the NSURL to my template.html file that I include in my app.  That's the part I don't get how to do.

Comment: Maybe this will help then [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686420/how-do-i-access-a-file-from-xcodes-supporting-files-group-in-app)